# Siguiente elemento html utilizando xpath

Tags: python, xpath

Estoy tratando de scrapear una seccion de una web, y me asalta la duda de como seleccionar el 'Siguiente elemento' del nodo que he seleccionado con xpath.

Un ejemplo práctico:

```
<div id="list">
    <strong>Color 1</strong>
    <span>Blue</span><br>
    <strong>Color 2</strong>
    <span>Red</span><br>
</div>
```

Ese código básicamente simula una tabla, en la cual numera los colores.
Tengo el xpath que llega hasta el nombre (la 'primera columna'):

```
color=html.xpath(//div[@id="list"]/strong[text()="Color 1"])
```

Mi duda es,¿  como puedo seleccionar el siguiente elemento que haya tras el nodo seleccionado ? Es decir, si llego al nodo Color 1, que me de Blue

En una tabla lo suelo hacer llegando hasta el nodo que contiene el nombre y tras eso regresando un elemento y entrando al 'td[2]', sin embargo aqui no puedo hacer eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de bastantes pruebas he conseguido resolverlo utilizando la query de xpath:

```
color=html.xpath('//div[@id="list"]/strong[text()="Color 1")]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()')[0]
```

Comment: Si esta es la solución, acepta la respuesta como valida para futuros usuarios.

Comment: No se puede aceptar una respuesta propia hasta pasadas 48h

Comment: Claro, pero es para que lo tengas en cuenta pasadas las 48h. :)